# initialize_paging(); is causing x86 OS to crash upon startup

Tags: c, gcc, x86, paging, osdev

I am currently attempting to reinvent the wheel and code an x86 OS using C and GAS assembler.

The OS currently starts up, initializes the GDT and IDT as well as interrupt handlers, then attempts to initialize paging (as done in the James Molloy operating system). The error occurs, I have deduced, upon setting up paging:

```c
void kernel_main(void) 
{   
    clear_screen();

    // Initialise all the ISRs and segmentation
    gdt_init();
    idt_init();

    initialize_paging(); // PROBLEM HAPPENS IN THIS FUNCTION

    nanos_printf("Hello, paging world!\n");

    uint32_t *ptr = (uint32_t*)0xA0000000;
    uint32_t do_page_fault = *ptr;

    return 0;
}
```

So, I attempted to debug that function and found that it comes from `switch_page_directory()`:

```c
void initialize_paging()
{

    uint32_t mem_end_page = 0x1000000;
    
    nframes = mem_end_page / 0x1000;
    frames = (uint32_t*)kmalloc(INDEX_FROM_BIT(nframes));
    memset(frames, 0, INDEX_FROM_BIT(nframes));
    
    kernel_directory = (page_directory_t*)kmalloc_a(sizeof(page_directory_t));
    current_directory = kernel_directory;


    int i = 0;
    while (i < placement_address)
    {
        alloc_frame( get_page(i, 1, kernel_directory), 0, 0);
        i += 0x1000;
    }
    register_interrupt_handler(14, page_fault);

    switch_page_directory(kernel_directory); // PROBLEM HAPPENS HERE
    
}
```

So, I looked in that function:

```c
void switch_page_directory(page_directory_t *dir)
{
    if (dir == NULL) {
        // Handle null pointer case
        return;
    }

    current_directory = dir;


    asm volatile("mov %0, %%cr3":: "r"(&dir->tablesPhysical));

    uint32_t cr0;
    asm volatile("mov %%cr0, %0": "=r"(cr0));
    cr0 |= 0x80000000; // Set paging bit
    asm volatile("mov %0, %%cr0":: "r"(cr0));
}
```

And from here I couldn't figure out what the problem is

I tried to edit my linker script to be the same as his, but that didn't work, so I reverted it:

```
ENTRY(_start)
 
SECTIONS
{

    . = 1M;
 
    .text BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.multiboot)
        *(.text)
    }
 
    .rodata BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.rodata)
    }

    .data BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.data)
    }
 
    .bss BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss)
    }
 
    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.comment)
        *(.eh_frame)
        *(.note*)
        *(.iplt)
        *(.igot)
    }

    end = .; _end = .; __end = .;
}
```

Essentially, whenever the OS gets to in the `switch_page_directory()` function the OS crashes in QEMU and the boot screen happens again, this happens many time a second.

Comment: Are you already in protected mode when you do this?

Comment: @zwol : I assumed they are based on the multiboot section in the linker script - if they are using GRUB, it will put them into 32-bit protected mode.

Comment: @Michael, mov to cr doesn't allow a memory source operand.

Comment: Can you run QEMU with the options `-d int -no-shutdown -no-reboot` and go to the bottom of the log and get a copy of the last few exceptions/interrupts that happened. It might indicate a problem.

Comment: I wrote an erroneous comment earlier since for some reason I thought one of your inline assembly statements was doing an `lgdt`. Sorry, I have deleted it. After calling `kmalloc_a` you aren't zeroing out that memory with something like `memset(kernel_directory, 0, sizeof(page_directory_t));`